# number of rows reducing because of order in R

Tags: r

Hi I am having a peculiar issue. While trying to order a data frame, my number of rows are reduced. Please see below:

```
> dim(y_data)
[1] 81  3
> y_data <- y_data[order(Date),] 
> dim(y_data)
[1] 55  3
> class(y_data)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
>
```

Can you please guide me?

Comment: It is a `tbl_df`.  You need `y_data %>% arrange(Date)`  Also, it is not clear whether the columns are `attach`ed or not.  it should be `y_data[order(y_data$Date),]`  assuming that 'Date' have the same length as the number of rows of the dataset

Comment: What are the dimensions of the object `Date`? I think you'll see that `Date` only has 55 rows

Comment: I did unique(y_data$Date) , the result is 81 different dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is a `tbl_df`, we can use the `tidyverse` methods to `arrange` the rows based on the 'Date'.

```
library(tidyr)
out <- y_data %>%
            arrange(Date)
```

---

In the OP's code,

```
y_data[order(Date),]
```

If there is no object 'Date', the above code would result in error.  As there is no error, it strongly suggests that the object is already created.

If the 'Date' object created in the global env is the same one that is used for creating the 'y_data', then it should work.  Based on the dimensions showed, it wouldn't be the case.  Here, we can extract the column specifically from the dataset using `$` or `[[`

```
y_data[order(y_data$Date),]
```

Comment: thanks your approach works but I am trying to understand why the above method did not work. I will accept your answer.

Comment: @itthrill  You may need to check whether there is a 'Date' object in your global environment which have length less than the number of rows of the dataset.  As I mentioned in the comments, the correct way to extract the column from the same dataset is using either `$` or `[[`

Comment: I had a Date object in my global environment. Thanks it is now clear. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

What are the dimensions of the object `Date`? What's happening in your code is that you're running order on an object called `Date`, not on `y_data$Date` as intended. You can either use `tidyverse` methods, as @akrun suggested, or correctly specify the object that you want to order by:

```
y_data <- y_data[order(y_data$Date),]
```

When you use the base `[]` notation, it doesn't know that `Date` refers to a column in `y_data`. It just looks for an object called `Date` in the environment and uses this. You need to explicitly specify that you're looking for `y_data$Date` by using the `$` notation.

Comment: I had a Date object in my global environment. Thanks it is now clear. Thanks for your help.